# What's the difference between "wild" and "wilding"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Especially if I speak of people? What's the difference?

Comment: Do you mean 'as an adjective to describe a person'?

Comment: Yes, I do. I don't understand what the difference is

Comment: please provide examples where "wild" and "wilding" are used to describe people. Your question lacks detail, and you are assuming that native and non-native speakers are familiar with both terms. They are not.

Comment: Are you a fan of "Games of Throne" by any chance? There is the neologism, "wildlings" (note the letter L) which refers to a tribe of lowly-educated men and women who live outside the Wall and are not allies of the Seven Kingdoms.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. I just started watching the series and I'm trying to learn English from it (:

Comment: @Mari-LouA -it's not as good as 'Better Saul Call'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  don't you mean, s'all good man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild is an adjective, when  used to describe a person it means "not civilised, lacking discipline, very enthusiastic".

Wilding as an adjective is only used in some old fashioned and poetic contexts and not usually applied to people at all.  It's normally used a noun (meaning a wild apple tree) or a gerund of the verb "to wild" meaning "to make or return an environment to the wild"